# How to turn a table with strings into a list of vectors in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset looks like this

```
> data.frame("letter" = letters, "words" = paste0(1:26,letters, letters,",", rev(letters),letters,5:26, ",", letters, 1:24, rev(letters)))
   letter          words
1       a    1aa,za5,a1z
2       b    2bb,yb6,b2y
3       c    3cc,xc7,c3x
4       d    4dd,wd8,d4w
5       e    5ee,ve9,e5v
...
```

And I would like to turn this table into

```
[[a]]
[1] "1aa" "za5" "a1z"

[[b]]
[1] "2bb" "yb6" "b2y"

[[c]]
[1] "3cc" "xc7" "c3x"

[[d]]
[1] "4dd" "wd8" "d4w"

[[e]]
[1] "5ee" "ve9" "e5v"
...
```

I have tried to use a for loop which works for me, however, when the `nrow` of this dataframe increase, it takes longer time. And I would like to know if there is a cleaner wayt to do so?

Your answer is much appreciated. 
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `strsplit` is what you are looking for. Try :

```
df = data.frame("letter" = letters, "words" = paste0(1:26,letters, letters,",", rev(letters),letters,5:26, ",", letters, 1:24, rev(letters)))
strsplit(as.character(df$words),',',fixed= TRUE)

[[1]]
[1] "1aa" "za5" "a1z"

[[2]]
[1] "2bb" "yb6" "b2y"

[[3]]
[1] "3cc" "xc7" "c3x"

[[4]]
[1] "4dd" "wd8" "d4w"

[[5]]
[1] "5ee" "ve9" "e5v"
```

Comment: @JimmyLee `setNames(strsplit(as.character(df$words),',',fixed= TRUE), df$letter)` to get the list with the names as in your example